# jQuery date range on more datePicker

Tags: jquery, scope, datepicker

I try to write a jQuery function, which takes the inputs inside the element and set the proper min/max date. But if i have more dateRinge on a page one takes the other's settings.
Every dateRange should have its own scope.

Here is a demo: http://jsbin.com/ahozug/1/edit, and here is my code:

**HTML**

```
     <div class="dateRange">
        <label>Label1</label>
        <input type="text" class="from" />
        <input type="text" class="to" />
    </div>
    <div class="dateRange">
        <label>Label2</label>
        <input type="text" class="from" />
        <input type="text" class="to" />
    </div>
```

**JS**

```
$.fn.dateRange = function(){
    var self = this;
    var selectedDate;
    $("input",this).prop('readonly', true);
    $('.from',this).datepicker({
        onClose:function( selectedDate ) {
            $( ".to",self ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
        }
    });

    $('.to',this).datepicker({
        onClose:function( selectedDate ) {
            $( ".from",self ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
        }
    });
};
$( "div.dateRange" ).dateRange();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$( ".to",self ) and $( ".from",self ) matches both "to" and "from", actually, since "self" is "window" in your case. Thus, settings are applied to both datepickers.

What you could try is using:

```
$(this).siblings(".from") instead of $(".from",self)
```

and

```
$(this).siblings(".to") instead of $(".to",self)
```

Comment: hmm i thought "this" is the scope of the selector, in this case $( "div.dateRange" ).

Comment: When you initialized it:

    $.fn.dateRange = function(){
        var self = this;

you set self = this, while "this" was "window"

Comment: is there a way to refer to the $( "div.dateRange" ) or whatever element the function applied on?

Comment: You can use $(this).parent(), of course, to get the div.dateRange.